# Chrome Network Panel - Html5 Video Explanation

Tags: google-chrome, video, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Developer Tools Network Panel I see my HTML5 video (MP4). I do not understand why it shows up 4 times. What does this mean? What means section "time" and "size" in this context? [It seems there are 4 steps necessary to load the video completely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZjIx.png)?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The server is answering in fragments:

> The server is successfully fulfilling a range request for the target resource by transferring one or more parts of the selected representation that correspond to the satisfiable ranges found in the request's Range header field1.

Excerpt from https://httpstatuses.com/206

Find the status code 206 in your pic, it is there in the second column.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: [Thank you for asking here!](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-s8j85DTL_aA/Tuq7U3f5PuI/AAAAAAAClOQ/okTm_AYNPqg/s1600/HTTP-Status-Cats-03.jpg)